# What is the difference between inner and outer vlans

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

I searched a google lot but am not able to find topic which can tell me the difference betweens inner vlans and outer vlans.  Or Atleast find more detail about them.

Can anyone please explain on this or at least give me some links to read about them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working with Q-in-Q, where there's an 802.1q tag within a tag, the *inner* and *outer* vlans are the inner most and outer most tags.

Comment: Is there online link for that to get more info

Comment: google "q-in-q" or "inner vlan"

Comment: thanks i have read the concept ,  When the Service provider tags with Outer valn , is it possible that two packets from different customer have same  Inner vlan and outer vlan . or they has to different or it does not matter

Answer (score -3):

-inner vlan is customer

-outer vlan is net

Comment: Welcome to this Stack Exchange. Although your answer explains how inner and outer VLANs *can* be used, they do not explain what the difference is. There are many more ways you can use inner and outer VLANs. Please consider improving your answer by adding additional information.